# How can I export data from listview(mysql offline database) to pdf or some type of a readable file?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion, xamarin.forms.listview

I have data from mysql database and displayed it in listview.  Now I want to export what's on my listview to a pdf file or a readable file.

I have been searching and it's pointing me towards syncfusion but there's not enough tutorial on it.  Perhaps a nuget i need to add to do this event.

This is the source for my binding.

```
public class Post
{
    //private const string V = "test";
    //from settingspage to show up in history
    string rain1lbl = Settings.rain1LocationSettings;
    string rain2lbl = Settings.rain2LocationSettings;
    string rain3lbl = Settings.rain3LocationSettings;

    //ID primary key that we will autoincrement
    //These are binding source for Historypage
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public static bool showLabel { get; set; }  //public class model


    public string rain1Lbl
    {
        get => rain1lbl;

        set
        {
            rain1lbl = Settings.rain1LocationSettings;
        }
    }

    public string rain2Lbl
    {
        get => rain2lbl;

        set
        {
            rain2lbl = Settings.rain2LocationSettings;
        }
    }

    public string rain3Lbl
    {
        get => rain3lbl;

        set
        {
            rain3lbl = Settings.rain3LocationSettings;
        }
    }


    public string CDateTime { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string rain1vol { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string rain2vol { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string rain3vol { get; set; }

    }

}
```

xaml file

```
<ListView x:Name="postListView" SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="true"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SeparatorColor="White" ItemSelected="listviewhandle_ItemSelected" >

<ListView.ItemTemplate>

         <!-- from the post.cs -->
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell >
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  Padding="1,2,1,0">

            <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ColumnSpacing="1"
                  RowSpacing="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions > 
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                      
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>                 
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  

                <!-- Date Time binding from Post.cs MVVM-->
               <Label x:Name="datetimeLabel" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding CDateTime}" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

            <!-- rain1 Row 1 odd rows are conrflowerblue-->
            <Label Grid.Row="1" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding rain1Lbl}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue"  />               
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding rain1vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue" /> 
                            <!-- endrow1   -->  

                            <!-- rain2 Row 2 -->
            <Label Grid.Row="2"  FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="{Binding showLabel}" Text="{Binding rain2Lbl}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>               
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding rain2vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Yellow" /> 

                            <!-- endrow2   -->

                    <!-- rain3 Row 3 -->
            <Label Grid.Row="3" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding rain3Lbl}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue" />                         
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding rain3vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue"/>
                            <!-- endrow3   -->  

</Grid>

      </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>       
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
       </StackLayout> 
</ContentPage>
```

cs file
    public partial class HistoryLogPage : ContentPage
    {
        public HistoryLogPage()
        {

```
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation);
        {

            conn.CreateTable<Post>();
            var posts= conn.Table<Post>().ToList();
            postListView.ItemsSource = posts;
            conn.Close();

        }
    }

    //to be able to know which item was selected
    void listviewhandle_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedPost = postListView.SelectedItem as Post;

        if(selectedPost != null)
        {
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PostDetail(selectedPost));
        }
    }

    void converbuttonHandle_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I find one way to export data from ListView to Excel file, you can take a look:

https://github.com/egbakou/ExportDataToExcel

Update:

```
   // Constructing header
                    Row row = new Row();

                    row.Append(
                        ConstructCell("No", CellValues.String),
                        ConstructCell("FullName", CellValues.String),
                        ConstructCell("Phone", CellValues.String)
                        );

                    // Insert the header row to the Sheet Data
                    sheetData.AppendChild(row);

                    // Add each product
                    foreach (var d in Developers)
                    {
                        row = new Row();
                        row.Append(
                            ConstructCell(d.ID.ToString(), CellValues.String),
                            ConstructCell(d.FullName, CellValues.String),
                            ConstructCell(d.Phone, CellValues.String));
                        sheetData.AppendChild(row);
                    }
```

According to the code, you can use Row.Append() to print header in excel, for example Column 1, column 2, column 3....

Then you can foreach ListView Itemsource to insert data in Excel. By your code, I see your ListView Itemsource is Items, so you can foreach Items to insert data in excel, like this:

```
 foreach (var d in Items)
        {
            row = new Row();
            row.Append(
                ConstructCell(d.CDateTime.ToString(), CellValues.String),
                ConstructCell(d.rain1Lbl.ToString(), CellValues.String),
                ConstructCell(d.rain1vol.ToString(), CellValues.String)
                 ConstructCell(d.showLabel.ToString(), CellValues.String),
                ConstructCell(d.rain2vol.ToString(), CellValues.String),
                 ConstructCell(d.rain3Lbl.ToString(), CellValues.String),
                ConstructCell(d.rain3vol.ToString(), CellValues.String));
            sheetData.AppendChild(row);
        }
```

Please

Comment: [assembly: Dependency(typeof(ExportFilesToLocation))] "Dependency" has squiggly on the bottom. missing a directive?

Comment: @chemobrain, It works fine at my side, I can find this excel file in Export file, you can try to clean your project and rebuild project, then try it again. if still have error directive, don't care error directive, just try to build project.

Comment: it is working now.. the nuget needs updating.. How to append my listview? Postistview. my codes are upthere
                        // Constructing header
                        Row row = new Row();

                        row.Append(
                            ConstructCell("No", CellValues.String),
                            ConstructCell("FullName", CellValues.String),
                            ConstructCell("Phone", CellValues.String)
                            );

Comment: chemobrain, please look at code that my update, if solved your issue, please remember to mark as answer for my reply, thanks.